# How to count days between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date, count

If I have a couple of strings `$startDate` and `$endDate` which are set to (for instance) `"2011/07/01"` and `"2011/07/17"` (meaning 1 July 2011 and 17 July 2011). How would I count the days from start date to end date? In the example given, it would be 17 days.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is the raw way to do it

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("2011/07/01");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("2011/07/17");

$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

// and you might want to convert to integer
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);
```

Comment: Will not work correctly when you have local dates that include a dayling savings time switchover, because on those dates you have days with 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: Actually, it says 16 days for those dates.. Do I need to make dates ignore daylight saving time..?

Comment: It should be 16 days because July 1 and July 17 are 16 days apart whereas July 1 and July 18 are 17 days apart

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt you have two solid dates, I don't see how daylight saving can affect this.

Comment: @Andy: if by "solid" you mean "literal", sure, but the question says "for instance", not "I need a solution for these specific dates in 2011 and don't care for any problems that might arise with other dates".

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt approved.

Comment: They say it's better to use the `Datetime` class, since `strtotime` can't compare dates further than 2038 year ...

Answer (score 36):

[Use `DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) (aka `date_diff`):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Or:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

You can then get the interval as a integer by calling `$interval->days`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with my initial strings of "2011/07/01" and "2011/07/17" ... "Call to undefined function date_diff().." . I'm using PHP 5.2.10

Comment: Per the documentation (linked at the top), this is PHP >= 5.3.0. For next time, please include the PHP version in your question.

Comment: does only work if you don't have a time in your Date Times otherwise it may return 1-2 days to few

Comment: bug : $interval->days return 6015 days ! And if i use the $interval->format("%d"), it only return the differences between the days, without taking into account the months and years.

Comment: Note that you need to add 1 to the result if you want to include both the start and end day in the count.

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a date_diff() function to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 3):

In case your DateTime has also hour:minutes:seconds and you still want to have the number of days..

```
   /**
     * Returns the total number of days between to DateTimes, 
     * if it is within the same year
     * @param $start
     * @param $end
     */
    public function dateTimesToDays($start,$end){
       return intval($end->format('z')) - intval($start->format('z')) + 1;
    }
```

https://github.com/dukeatcoding/timespan-converter

Answer (score 3):

```
$date1 = date_create("2017-04-15");
$date2 = date_create("2017-05-18");

//difference between two dates
$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);

//count days
echo 'Days Count - '.$diff->format("%a");
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. For those who are still on PHP 5.2 (DateTime::diff was introduced in 5.3), this solution works:

```
function howDays($from, $to) {
    $first_date = strtotime($from);
    $second_date = strtotime($to);
    $offset = $second_date-$first_date; 
    return floor($offset/60/60/24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of days (if any), the number of hours (if any), minutues (if any) and seconds, you can do the following:

```
$previousTimeStamp = strtotime("2011/07/01 21:12:34");
$lastTimeStamp = strtotime("2013/09/17 12:34:11");

$menos=$lastTimeStamp-$previousTimeStamp;

$mins=$menos/60;
if($mins<1){
$showing= $menos . " seconds ago";
}
else{
$minsfinal=floor($mins);
$secondsfinal=$menos-($minsfinal*60);
$hours=$minsfinal/60;
if($hours<1){
$showing= $minsfinal . " minutes and " . $secondsfinal. " seconds ago";

}
else{
$hoursfinal=floor($hours);
$minssuperfinal=$minsfinal-($hoursfinal*60);
$days=$hoursfinal/24;
if($days<1){
$showing= $hoursfinal . "hours, " . $minssuperfinal . " minutes and " . $secondsfinal. " seconds ago";

}
else{
$daysfinal=floor($days);
$hourssuperfinal=$hoursfinal-($daysfinal*24);
$showing= $daysfinal. "days, " .$hourssuperfinal . " hours, " . $minssuperfinal . " minutes and " . $secondsfinal. " seconds ago";
}}}

echo $showing;
```

You could use the same logic if you want to add months and years.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to count is,

```
$currentdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$after1yrdate =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($data)));

$diff = (strtotime($after1yrdate) - strtotime($currentdate)) / (60 * 60 * 24);

echo "<p style='color:red'>The difference is ".round($diff)." Days</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i created a function in which if you pass two dates than it will return day wise value. For better understanding please see the output of start date : **2018-11-12 11:41:19** and End Date **2018-11-16 12:07:26**

```
private function getTimeData($str1,$str2){
$datetime1 = strtotime($str1);
$datetime2 = strtotime($str2);
$myArray = array();
if(date('d', $datetime2) != date('d', $datetime1) ||  date('m', $datetime2) != date('m', $datetime1) || date('y', $datetime2) != date('y', $datetime1)){
    $exStr1 = explode(' ',$str1);
    $exStr2 = explode(' ',$str2);
    $datediff = strtotime($exStr2[0]) - strtotime($exStr1[0]);
    $totalDays = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $actualDate1 = $datetime1;
    $actualDate2 = date('Y-m-d', $datetime1)." 23:59:59";
    $interval  = abs(strtotime($actualDate2)-$actualDate1);
    $minutes   = round($interval / 60);
    $myArray[0]['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $actualDate1); 
    $myArray[0]['endDate'] = $actualDate2;
    $myArray[0]['minutes'] = $minutes;
    $i = 1;
    if($totalDays > 1){    
        for($i=1; $i<$totalDays; $i++){
            $dayString = "+".$i." day";
            $edate = strtotime($dayString, $actualDate1);
            $myArray[$i]['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d', $edate)." 00:00:00"; 
            $myArray[$i]['endDate'] = date('Y-m-d', $edate)." 23:59:59"; 
            $myArray[$i]['minutes'] = 1440;
        }
    }
    $actualSecDate1 = date('Y-m-d', $datetime2)." 00:00:00";
    $actualSecDate2 = $datetime2;
    $interval  = abs(strtotime($actualSecDate1)-$actualSecDate2);
    $minutes   = round($interval / 60);
    $myArray[$i]['startDate'] = $actualSecDate1; 
    $myArray[$i]['endDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $actualSecDate2); 
    $myArray[$i]['minutes'] = $minutes;
}
else{
    $interval  = abs($datetime2-$datetime1);
    $minutes   = round($interval / 60);
    $myArray[0]['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime1); 
    $myArray[0]['endDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime2);
    $myArray[0]['minutes'] = $minutes;
}

return $myArray;
}
```

> Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [startDate] => 2018-11-12 11:41:19
        [endDate] => 2018-11-12 23:59:59
        [minutes] => 739
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [startDate] => 2018-11-13 00:00:00
        [endDate] => 2018-11-13 23:59:59
        [minutes] => 1440
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [startDate] => 2018-11-14 00:00:00
        [endDate] => 2018-11-14 23:59:59
        [minutes] => 1440
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [startDate] => 2018-11-15 00:00:00
        [endDate] => 2018-11-15 23:59:59
        [minutes] => 1440
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [startDate] => 2018-11-16 00:00:00
        [endDate] => 2018-11-16 12:07:26
        [minutes] => 727
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `date_diff` to calculate the difference between two dates:

```
$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff =  date_diff($date1 , $date2);
echo  $diff->format("%R%a days");
```