# How to get duration of days between today and 2011-5-20 in days by PHP?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count days between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php)

Seems there's only a javascript version,what about in PHP?

Comment: @Shakti Singh ,my question is to count between `today` and another day,so a little different..

Comment: No diff at all. get today date by `date('Y-m-d')` function

Comment: Possible Duplicate: answer [How to count days between two dates in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Taken almost directly from an article I wrote a few weeks ago: [Working with Date and Time in PHP](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/working-with-date-and-time-in-php/)

```
$today = new DateTime();
$ref = new DateTime("2011-05-20");

$diff = $today->diff($ref);
echo "the difference is {$diff->days} days" . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the seconds they differ, and you can easily calculate the amount of days.

```
$oFirstDate = new DateTime($sDateFormat);
$oSecondDate = new DateTime($sDateFormat2);
$iSeconds = $oFirstDate->getTimeStamp() - $oSecondDate->getTimeStamp();
$iDays = $iSeconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Shakti; with minimal changes, the script from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php) will work for you:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
$datetime2 = date_create('2011-05-21');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->days . " days difference.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a generic-ish function for stuff like that:

```
function timediffIn($time, $unit, $human = False){

    $tokens = array (
        'years'   => 31536000,
        'months'  => 2592000,
        'weeks'   => 604800,
        'days'    => 86400,
        'hours'   => 3600,
        'minutes' => 60,
        'seconds' => 1
    );

    if(!array_key_exists($unit, $tokens)){
        if ($human) print "No such unit: $unit\n";
        return FALSE;   
    } 
    if(!strtotime($time)){
        if ($human) print "$time does not translate into a valid time\n";
        return FALSE;
    }

    $elapsed = time() - strtotime($time);

    $interval = $tokens[$unit];
    if($human){
        print "It has been " . floor($elapsed / $interval) . " $unit since $time\n";
    }
    return floor($elapsed / $interval);

}
```

HTH

Comment: Obviously, the "human" parameter is for debug purposes / command line scripts - you can safely strip out everything concerning it.