# PHP- For loop not being accessed

Tags: php

So I have the following for loop:

```
$arr = [];
for($x = date('j', strtotime('this week')); $x <= date('j', strtotime('this week + 6 days')); $x++)
            {
                dd('test');
                $arr[$x] = [
                    'y' => $x,
                    's' => 0,
                    'c' => 0,
                    'cl' => 0
                ];
            }
            dd('test2');
```

The problem is that the loop is never accessed...the dd() returns 'test2' but the for loop is not accessed and it doesn't return any errors.
I have a similar one:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= date('t', strtotime('today')); $x++)
            {
                $arr[$x] = [
                    'y' => $x . ' ' . date('M', strtotime('today')),
                    's' => 0,
                    'c' => 0,
                    'cl' => 0
                ];
            }
```

And this one works perfectly. What I am trying to do is generate indexes for $arr based on this week's days or in the following case based on this month's days. I simply don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.
Thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: I'd var_dump `date('j', strtotime('this week'))` to see what val you're getting

Comment: https://3v4l.org/LrLcv

Comment: I am pretty sure 'this week' is not what you want. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to achieve an array with key based on this week's days. date('j', strtotime('this week')) returns 29

Comment: Hi Alphonse, did you solve your problem? If yes, mark it as solved to help keep S.O clean and other people with the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you have with:

```
$x = date('j', strtotime('this week')); //returns 29

$x <= date('j', strtotime('this week + 6 days')) // returns 4
```

And never enter to the loop (the operation is: 29 < 4).

If you change the `j` for a `z` (in the PHP oficial documentation for date:

> The day of the year (starting from 0)

) you will obtain the:

```
x: 148 < x: 154
```

Then, inside the loop, you can use the `j` to store the day of the week, and the loop will work.

If you want to go between 2 dates, adding days, there is others solutions too like:[How to count days between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653882/how-to-count-days-between-two-dates-in-php#3653960)

Hope it helps!

Comment: The day of the year won't work in the last week of December.

Comment: It works, but the count starts in 0. If you want to work with dates, PHP has a very powerful options with date, strtotime and so one. You can even work with leap year or know which day of the month was 12/02/1893 (for instance). Maybe the solution here is work with pure date in the for, like (in pseudocode): x=date(now); x<date(now+6days); x=date(+1day)

Comment: In the last week of the year, it will try to loop from something like 360 to 2, and that will have the same problem as going from 29 to 4 using the day of the month.

Comment: Thank you! Due to your explanation I figured out a way to adapt my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('this week Sunday');
$endDate = new DateTime('this week Saturday');

while( $date<=$endDate ){
   // do some stuff
   // ...

   $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your solution is doing instead of just pasting a piece of code

Comment: it's very self explanatory nothing fancy here just looping though days of current week using DateTime class and while loop, the loop will stop execution after reaching Saturday and uses $date object as reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Soution** found due to @JP. Aulet's explanation:

```
for($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++)
            {
                $date = date('j', strtotime('this week +' .$x . 'days'));
                $arr[$date] = [
                    'y' => $date,
                    's' => 0,
                    'c' => 0,
                    'cl' => 0
                ];
            }
```