# How to find the difference in days between two dates

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)

If I have two dates - how do I find the real difference in days between two dates? You must take things like leap years and the number of days in each month into account.

How many days are between something like `2010-03-29` and `2009-07-16`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: This can be found right on the PHP date function page:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#100251

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and simple math:

```
   $daylen = 60*60*24;

   $date1 = '2010-03-29';
   $date2 = '2009-07-16';

   echo (strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2))/$daylen;
```

Comment: `echo abs(floor((strtotime("2010-03-29")-strtotime("2009-07-16"))/(60*60*24)));`

Comment: I agree with `abs`, but not `floor`. Those are days being compared to days, `floor` or not, same result. Besides, the number of days between X and Y might be 232.67 and it's still valid (unless OP specifically asked for it to be rounded).

Comment: Above solution gives exactly, result is in + or - days.

Comment: in regions with daylight savings time, some days have 23/25 hours. You will run into trouble then. Use DateTime.

Answer (score 4):

check out PHP [DateTime](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) class.  It deals with all the gory details so you can just do regular subtraction.

```
$d1=date_create('1999-10-23');
$d2=date_create('2004-04-17');

$i=date_diff($d2,$d1);
echo $i->format('%a');
```

Comment: 1. This should be $i->format('%d') (forgot the %)
2. For the total number of days use '%a'
3. There is a bug in the Windows version that will always return 6015 when using this function (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184)

Comment: it doesn't work properly, i get sometimes 0 when i try to play with months value

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$date1 = strtotime("2010-03-29");
$date2 = strtotime("2009-07-16");
$dateDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
echo "Differernce is $fullDays days";
?>
```