# Time To Percent Using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, date

This may sound like a dumb question, but how can I convert the time between two dates to a percent?

I am using this Jquery plugin: http://tinacious.github.io/goalProgress/

The script on page that calculates the percent is:

```
$('#timerGoal').goalProgress({
                    goalAmount: 100,
                    currentAmount: 40,
                    textBefore: '',
                    textAfter: '% Completed.'
                });
```

Where it says `goalAmount:` I'd like that to remain at `100`, but where it says `currentAmount: 40,` I'd somehow like to find the difference in percentage between two days, I know I'd have to set a start date, current date, and end date to find a percentage.

I'm certain part of the code would have to be:

```
$startDate = '01/01/2015 12:00:00';
$currentDate = date('d/M/Y H:i:s');
$endDate = '02/15/2015 12:00:00';
```

Finding the difference in two dates is fairly easy, but it's the third date thing I cannot grasp, especially to make it a percentage.

Any ideas?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

[Taken from: [How to find the difference in days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502832/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates) ]

```
$daylen = 60*60*24;

   $date1 = '2010-03-29';
   $date2 = '2009-07-16';

   echo (strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2))/$daylen;
```

But everything I read on is two dates not three.

Here is what I've come up with.
It's not calculating percentages yet, but it's something to possibly go off of:

```
$startDate = '08/01/2015 12:00:00';
$currentDate = date('d/M/Y H:i:s');
$endDate = '09/01/2015 12:00:00';

$startDate =str_replace(array(':', '/', ' '), '', $startDate);
$currentDate =str_replace(array(':', '/', ' '), '', $currentDate);
$endDate =str_replace(array(':', '/', ''), ' ', $endDate);

$mainPercent = $endDate - $startDate;

$actualPercent = $endDate - $currentDate;

$displayPercent =  $actualPercent/$mainPercent * 100;

echo $displayPercent;
```

With todays date being `08/07/2015` I am getting `901.2015119993` which is obviously not a percent, but it's a start.

**Working Solution:**

```
$startDate = strtotime('08/01/2015 12:00:00');
$currentDate = time(date('d/M/Y H:i:s'));
$endDate = strtotime('09/15/2015 12:00:00');

$dateDivideBy = $endDate - $startDate;
$dateDivide = $currentDate - $startDate;

$divideProduct = $dateDivide / $dateDivideBy;

$datePercent = round($divideProduct * 100);

echo $datePercent;
```

With this working code and todays date being `08/07/2015` the value of `$datePercent` is `14`.

Comment: what's the point of `date('01/01/2015...')`? None of those are formatting characters, so you might as well just have `$start = '01/01/...'` and if you want to find the diff between time strings, you should `strtotime()` them into integers, on which you CAN do math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between two times, by itself, really can't be converted to a percentage. It's just a period of time. In order to figure out what percentage is complete, you would need to know how long the entire goal is supposed to take (an estimated time, I assume.) Then you can figure out the percentage like this:

```
ElapsedTime / TotalTime * 100
```

The total time would be `End Date - Start Date`, and the elapsed time would be `now - start date`.

Rather than using string functions to manipulate the dates, it would be better to use DateTime functions.

```
$startDate = '08/01/2015 12:00:00';
$endDate = '09/01/2015 12:00:00';

$startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
$currentDate = new DateTime(); // defaults to now
$endDate = new DateTime($endDate);

$totalTime = $endDate->diff($startDate)->format('%a');
$elapsedTime = $currentDate->diff($startDate)->format('%a');
// diff returns a DateInterval object; calling its format method 
// with %a returns the number of days in the interval

$percent = ($elapsedTime / $totalTime) * 100;
```

Comment: That's why I was thinking percentage using 3 times.
My idea is an established start time and end time being 100% and then the current time to end time being the other percentage. I'm going to do some experimenting and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Looks like we are thinking along the same lines now :)
I was confused at first, but I think I can figure this out. Thanks for jogging my brain into thinking.

I will leave this up so when I find a solution I can post an answer for any possible future visits.

Comment: Thanks. Here is something I think I can work with, but cannot think of how to do. Let's say I have the date `01/01/2015 12:00:00` how can I convert that to a number like `01012015120000`? I think I can come up with a decent code if I can convert all the dates to just numbers.

Comment: JavaScript `Date` objects are just a representations of milliseconds, you can add and subtract them as you'd like without converting them.

Comment: I've posted in my question the code I have written so far. I'm not getting percentages yet, but it's a start. Any suggestions based off of it?

Comment: @JesseElser I added an example of how to calculate this using PHP DateTime objects.

Comment: I like it :) Sadly I just got it solved and was just about to post my solution :) Yours works so I will mark it as accepted, but I will add mine into my question if you want to take a look at the other possible one that works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your desired outcome, where `result` is the resulting percent difference between `start_actual_time` and `percent_time`:

```
var percent_time= new Date("01/17/2013 11:20");
var start_actual_time = new Date("01/17/2012 11:20");
var end_actual_time = new Date("01/17/2014 11:20");


var range = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;
var diff = end_actual_time - percent_time;

var result = (diff / range)*100;
```

In this example, `start_actual_time` and `percent_time` are 40% different.