# Comparing two SQL dates with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)

I'm trying to compare two dates that are stored in two PHP variables. `$curDate` and `$prevDate` are stored in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. To simply display them, I've been using `date("n,j,Y", strtotime($prevDate))` or some other combination of the first parameters of the date function.

I want to compare the `$curDate` and `$prevDate` on the scale of days, but the trouble is, the 31st could be 1 day from the 1st so if I just look at the date in this way then I can't handle that behavior.

I've looked into the PHP Function `JulianToJD()` but can't just pass the SQL date, formatted thru the `date()` and `strtotime()` function.

Can someone help me figure out a clever way of comparing two dates on the scale of days while paying attention to the end of months?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2040560/469210

Comment: @borrible This worked. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See stackoverflow.com/q/2040560/469210.  I.e. calculate the diff of the dates and apply the floor function:

```
floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it two ways:

MySQL:

```
SELECT (TO_DAYS(curDate) - TO_DAYS(prevDate)) as Days ...
```

which gives you the difference in days ([TO_DAYS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) returns the number of days since year 0)

PHP, using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$prev = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Y-m-d', $prevDate);
$cur = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Y-m-d', $curDate);

$days = $cur->diff($prev)->format('%a');
```

Comment: this looks good, however, I get an error on the first line of PHP, `$prev=....`: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Comment: Woops, sorry. take out the "new" portion. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: +1 I don't like the MySQL way; the PHP way is nice and clean!

Comment: @Marc Taking out the `new` did fix that error, but I don't think this works as it should. I printed out `$prevDate` and `$curDate` which are `2011-03-12` and `2011-07-04`, respectively. The output for days is `6015`???

Comment: @Marc as a side note, those date outputs by nature might seem ambiguous with the month/day, but they are in the Y-m-d format.

Comment: That's why I never use strtotime(). It usually works well, but on ambiguous dates it'll screw up silently and ruin your day. It's fairly rare to have a completely arbitrary date - usually you know what the format is, so it's best to use createfromformat and save yourself all the extra parsing/overhead of strtotime, plus you get far more dependable results.

Comment: @Marc I don't *use* strtotime() at all with the dates inputted to your code. Here's the even weirder part... Any two dates I compare with your code **ALL** come out with the result `6015`.

Comment: Known bug on Windows: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184

Comment: @Marc Oh, lovely. Any other routes I can go here that doesn't use MySQL?

Comment: @Marc NVM. borrible's link to another question worked.

Comment: You could format the dates to `'U'`, which gives you a standard unix timestamp. You can then convert that to days by dividing by 86400 (seconds in a day) and work off that.

Comment: @Marc true... borrible's solution he posted is actually much simpler, thank you for your help though.