# Collect the number of days between two dates

Tags: php, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)

Collect the number of days between two dates, for example
02/11/2012
And between
02/12/2012

The result is the number of days = 1 day

Comment: You've tagged this AJAX and PHP.  Do you need to know how to do this in Javascript, or PHP?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function dateDiff ($d1, $d2) {

  return round(abs(strtotime($d1)-strtotime($d2))/86400);

}
```

The function uses the PHP ABS() absolute value to always return a postive number as the number of days between the two dates.

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.3 you can use [DateTime::Diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
<?php
  $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
  $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Comment: This is probably significantly slower than using strtotime(), but it is an alternative ;)

Comment: @Jeroen: Although does take in to account DST/Leap Years and other factors...

Comment: What difference would that make? UNIX timestamps as returned by strtotime() is simply the amount of seconds since jan 1 1970, so that automatically 'takes into account' leap years.

Comment: @Jeroen: That comment was in regards to manipulating the `DateTime` object, which I feel is more reliable than basing calculations off each day having 86400 seconds. The DateTime object (and its advancements with PHP 5.3) are more stable; that's all I was getting at.

Comment: Of course, if you're gonna be manipulating it, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (strtotime('02/12/2012') - strtotime('02/11/2012')) / (24*60*60);
```

This line converts both dates to unix timestamps, subtracts them and divides this by the amount of seconds in a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date to a timestamp with the strtotime() function:

```
$date1 = strtotime("02/11/2012");
$date2 = strtotime("02/12/2012");
$difference = $date1 - $date2;
```

Then you have the difference in seconds which is a new timestamp, so you can convert this to days with the date() function:

```
$days = date("d", $difference);
```