# Difference between 2 dates (not considering years)

Tags: php, date, datetime, mktime

I have a database with different domains and the dates when they were registered and I need to show when they will be expired (1 year registration). For example:

domain1.com - registered 11/19/2012 (mm-dd-yyyy) - expires in 365 days.
domain2.com - registered 11/20/2011 (mm-dd-yyyy) - expires in 1 day.

I have been looking for different options and questions (i.e. [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)) but they are a little bit different (I don't need years to take into account) and I am not an expert in PHP and dates.

I think that one option could be removing from the total the difference of years (*365) but I will not take into account years of 366.

Thank you in advanced!
Regards,

Paul

Comment: So basically, you want to find the difference between "*the date plus one year* and *today*", expressed in days, right? There's a convenient method for PHP 5.3+ and a not so convenient method for PHP 5.2-. Which do you need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php  This might help you

Comment: Hi deceze, I should have clarified it since the begging. I need it for PHP 5.3. thx.

Comment: Hi Akhilraj N S. I have already checked that answer but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I have tried to modify the code in order to get the result I'm expecting but I think I did something wrong somewhere :\ but thx for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may useful this example.

```
$date1 = "11/19/2012";
$date2 = "11/20/2011";
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Try it & provide appropriate response !!

Comment: Hi Dev, thx! for your response. This is the same response as question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php I took a look at it but I didn't work for me. Anyway I couldn't find anything accurate so I am implementing your solution adding 365 * ($years) + 31 * ($months) and taking into account leap years. I just need to figure out how to add the corresponding amount of days to each month but I think I will create some array for that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the databases date functions to work this out for you.. with mysql it would be along the lines of

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(start_date, NOW()) AS days_remaining FROM table_name
```

See here for more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: That seems to be a really good solution!
I tried to implement it in mysql and it returns some negative values that are not OK. I tried to add SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY(start_date), DAY(NOW())) and so on but it returns null. I have also tried but still not able to implement it from PHP.