# integer value to compare to todays date

Tags: php

I have an form field thats is saved on the db as an integer. Its a simple due day.

`<input name="due_day" type="text" id="due_day" class="input-mini" maxlength="2" />`

What I would like to do is to compare this due day value to the current date to see the difference. For example the bill due date is every 15th of the month and today is the 12th of Dec. I would like show the difference from today to the next due day which is the 15th of december and display that value. How should I go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $due_day   = $_POST['due_day'];
 $today_day = date('d');
 echo ($due_day - $today_day);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't think I can get the difference between a date and an integer that easily.

Comment: No problem. I just removed that redundant param from `date` - it defaults to `now`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PHP Date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get the difference between 2 dates and you can display it however you need to.