# SELECT difference between two dates and sum

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum

I have this table in mysql

```
Date one   | Date tow   | 
2012-05-20 | 2012-05-04 | = 16 days 
2012-05-12 | 2012-05-08 | = 4 days
                          = 20 days
```

and i want to select difference between two dates and then sum all days.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you should do it in MySQL, you could use DATEDIFF function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dateone, datetwo) AS d FROM tablename
```

and then you could aggregate this result the way you want, example

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(dateone, datetwo)) AS s FROM tablename
```

You can do it also in PHP after fetching the dates

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(`Date one`, `Date tow`)) FROM `Table`
```

See [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Note that in MySQL, you do not need to use `GROUP BY` in order to be able to use the aggregate function `SUM()`. In that case, MySQL will regard all rows as a single group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. hope it will sort out the issue.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DATE1,DATE2)), FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEDIFF` function in mysql.

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT DATEDIFF(one,tow) AS diff, (@runtot := @runtot + DATEDIFF(one,tow)) AS runningsum
FROM table
```