# How to count fractional days between 2 dates

Tags: php

I've got the following code, but this gives me whole numbers:

```
<?php
   $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11 00:00:00');
   $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-11 00:00:10');
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
   echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

How do I count days and show the decimal points to?  In the example above, there is a difference of 10 seconds, how do I get it to display 0.000000something days?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: `diff()` will only ever return the difference in days. Your two dates have the same days, so there'll be no difference. You'd want to convert to a plain "number of seconds" difference instead, and format that into an hh:mm:ss type string.

Comment: Just divide the difference in seconds by the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: I know examples exist of seconds.  I am not after that.  I am after days to the decimal point. i.e. if there is a difference of 24 hours, I want to see 0. days.  If there is a difference of 1 and a half days, I want to see 1.5 days.  If there is a difference of 1 day and 3/4 of a day, I want to see 1.75 days etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)?

```
$oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
$datetime1 = strtotime('2009-10-11 00:00:00');
$datetime2 = strtotime('2009-10-11 00:00:10');
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1; // seconds
$days = $interval / $oneDay; // fractions of days
```

Comment: Perhaps because strtotime simply converts to unix timestamps, which aren't daylight savings aware

Comment: But this shows seconds, I want to show days with decimal points, i.e. 1 and a half days is 1.5 days etc.

Comment: If both dates are in the same timezone (so the same dayligt saving rules apply) why would you care? The difference would still be the same.

Comment: I edited my code to compute fractions of days, not days + extra seconds.