# How can you get the number of days since year 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, date, date-math

It's the equivalent of the [MySQL ***to_days()*** function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days).

Is there a builtin `PHP` function that does this, or do I need to cobble something together?

Comment: There's no such thing as Year 0 in the Gregorian calendar. You go from 1 BC to 1 AD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Comment: [*This is the answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2040589/767881)

Comment: @Ravinder that eill not work as that answer converts the date into a timestamp - which starts in 1970. So there are about 365.225 times 1970 days missing ;)

Comment: @heiglandreas: Got you.

Answer (score 8):

You'd need to write your own but it's not hard:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$zero = new DateTime('0000-00-00'); // -0001-11-30 - Nov 30, 1 BC. Interesting.
$diff = $now->diff($zero);
echo $diff->format('%a days'); // 735728 days
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jw2SSN) using the literal year zero. You obviously would want to put a valid date in there instead.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$zero = new DateTime('0001-01-01'); 
$diff = $now->diff($zero);
echo $diff->format('%a days'); // 735330 days
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2mqELH)

As a one liner:

```
echo (new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime('0001-01-01'))->format('%a days');
```

As a function:

```
function toDays($date) {
    return (new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime($date))->format('%a');
}
```

Comment: Hyperlinks are dead John

Comment: I'll have to update them next time I'm in front of a computer. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: 00 as month or day means 01 - 1. Which means 01-01 - one month and one day. Therefore you get 30th of november.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Julian day count, i.e. with cal_to_js(), see http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.cal-to-jd.php, even if there was no year 0 in the Gregorian calendar.