# Subtract two dates to display number of Days

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime("$da[tofollowon]");

    $datetime2 = new DateTime();

    $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    $days = $difference->days;
?>
```

Above php code displays difference in two dates, but i want to subtract these two dates datetime2 from  datetime1  which should even display negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $d1 = strtotime("2014-01-10"); // or your date as well
 $d2 = strtotime("2014-01-01");
 $datediff = $d1 - $d2;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24)).' days';
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$start = strtotime('2010-01-25');
$end = strtotime('2010-02-20');
$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

For more :- [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)