# Finding difference between two dates in PHP 5.2 or higher

Tags: php, datetime, datediff, date-difference

I want to find date difference between two dates in PHP 5.2

I am not sure if `date_diff` can be used. The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/date_diff) says `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`

I do not understand what this means. Does it mean it is available only in PHP 5, beginning from version 5.3.0?

I wanted to use the solution mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates), however if date_diff does not work in 5.2, can anyone help me with what else I can use?

Comment: A related question is why are you still running PHP 5.2? That is very old... PHP 5.6 was just released the other day - you should upgrade.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange : Moreover, since PHP 5.6 has been released PHP 5.4 has only security fix for a year. So it should be a good idea to upgrade PHP.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange - Most people forget that the programmers writing code has little control over the server versions in which it runs due to a million reasons. In my case it is a partner company's server where we need to deploy code. It has many other legacy applications running and they are not in a position to upgrade until they have ported everything off. 

I am sure most people are aware how obsolete these versions are, but it is not as straightforward as just upgrading. In the real world not everything can be as easily fixed.

Comment: Also, I checked the answers in the question to which mine was marked as a duplicate - however none of them really answers it. I do not think writing a whole new class is required to do a simple date diff in PHP 5.2, as the answers in that question suggests.

Comment: To answer your question - PHP 5>=5.3 means you need "PHP5" and version 5.3 or greater

Comment: @TheShiftExchange - thank you for that piece of information.

Comment: You could use `strtotime` and do `$diff = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);`. That will give you the difference in dates in seconds. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php