# Find number of days since spesific date in PHP

Tags: php

I have dates in this format: "28.03.2014".
So DD-MM-YYYY.

How do I calculate the number of days since this date?

I found another question where the accepted answer was pretty long, and the date was also in another format.

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Is this still the way to do things, and do I have to reformat my dates to fit into strtotime?

Comment: `strtotime` will take practically any date format. Try the existing code and see if it works!

Comment: What exactly is "long" about, e.g., this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16177475/476 ? If you have dates in a different format, use `DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date)` instead of `new DateTime($date)`.

Comment: If it is preetty long, use this :) echo floor((time() - strtotime('28.03.2014')) / (60*60*24) );

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) in my composer projects for this and similar purposes.

It'd be as easy as this:

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2010-01-01');
echo $dt->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
```