# Php Split date in time intervals

Tags: php, time, period

I need to express a past date to now difference in a human readable format (e.g. 1day 2hours 1minute etc..).

Here my try:

```
<?php
function datediff($datatodiff){
    $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d G:i:s", $datatodiff/1000))
    $now = new DateTime();
    $interval = $date->diff($now);
    return $interval->format("%m month %d days %h hours and %i minuts");
}
?>
```

My problem is that if I have to split the date in hours and minutes, I want to see all the time interval expressed.

My attempt is working, but only if i show all time units.
I can clarify with an example.

`1 year 4 months 3 days 1 hour 2 minutes`

if i remove the months the output is `1 year 3 days 1 hour 2 minutes` but i'd like:

`1 year 123 days 1 hour 2 minutes`. This behaviour with all units

The time units that will be displayed are chosen by the user.
I also tried Carbon lib without success.

In Android I use period formatter from JodaTime Lib if can help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: Is your attempt is working a bit? it's giving fatel error?

Comment: You need to change your code like this:-

    <?php
    function datediff($datatodiff){
       $date1 = new DateTime($datatodiff);
     $date2 = new DateTime();
    
    // The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);
    
    // Call the format method on the DateInterval-object
    echo $diff->format('%a Day and %h hours');
    }
     datediff('2015-10-02');
    ?>

Output:- http://prntscr.com/74dk83