# Number of days between two time stamps

Tags: php, timestamp

How can I calculate the number of days between two times, I have a one time field in my table name `active_time`, following is the code I have tried but it gives me number value around thousands whereas I have queried for number of days:

```
$now =strtotime("now"); // Current time
$your_date = $data[$i]['active_time'];
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
$value= floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

result:16569

Comment: Is it `PHP`? If so, add it as a tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Comment: It may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `$value= ceil(abs($now - $your_date) / 86400);`

Answer (score 0):

The datediff is in milliseconds. You need to do.

Multiply by an additional 1000.

$value= floor($datediff/(1000*60*60*24));