# PHP date_diff() return value

Tags: php, date, difference

I tried to get the difference from two dates with this code

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Is there a way to return an integer instead of a formatted string?

Thanks :)

Comment: `intval($diff->format("%a"))`?

Comment: *return an integer* You mean the difference in seconds? Or what?

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2040589

Comment: Thanks @SirajulHaq :)

Comment: this is how you can achieve `strtotime($date);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert date into timestamp and then subtract the dates and divide the difference with 60*60*24, you will gets days as integer value ..

```
<?php 
$date1=strtotime("2013-03-15");
$date2=strtotime("2013-12-12");
$diff= $date2-$date1;
echo floor($diff/(60*60*24));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can choose any of following

**Type Casting**

```
 echo (int) $diff->format("%R%a");
```

**another way** using PHP `intval()`

```
  echo intval($diff->format("%R%a"));
```