# How to calculate difference of two string dates in days using PHP?

Tags: php, string, date, datediff

I have two date variables:

```
$dnow = "2016-12-1";
$dafter = "2016-12-11";
```

I want to calculate the difference of this two dates which are in string format so how do I calculate?
I used

```
date_diff($object, $object2)
```

but it expecting two date object, and I have dates in **String** format
, After using `date_diff` I get following error

> Message: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the number of days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,  use **[date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)**

```
$dnow = "2016-12-1";
$dafter = "2016-12-11";
$date1=date_create($dnow);
$date2=date_create($dafter);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
print_r($diff);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/689030)**

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`strtotime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to create a timestamp of both dates and compare those values.

```
<?php

$start = strtotime('2016-12-1');
$end = strtotime('2016-12-11');
$diffInSeconds = $end - $start;
$diffInDays = $diffInSeconds / 86400;
```

Comment: The code return difference time in second. You should convert it to day.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day, so divide the result by this number.

Answer (score 3):

```
$datetime1=date_create($dnow);
$datetime2 = date_create($dafter);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
//%R is used to show +ive or -ive symbol and %a is used to show you numeric difference
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the number of days, then you can use the [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object's `days` property.

```
$day1 = '2016-12-1';
$day2 = '2016-12-11';
$days_elapsed = date_diff(date_create(date($day1)), date_create($day2)) -> days;

echo $days_elapsed; //Outputs 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dnow = "2016-12-1";
$dafter = "2016-12-11";
$dnow=date_create($dnow);
$dafter=date_create($dafter);
$difference=date_diff($dnow,$dafter);
```

Comment: Duplicate of @krunal answer.

Comment: You only changed variable name, but solution is same.