# calculate the number of nights between two dates

Tags: php, date

I want how to extract the exact number of nights. I tried to achieve this by two ways but doesn't work. It return 20 nights but in real, it is 21 nights (March have 31 days)

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("14-03-2017");                                   
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("04-04-2017");                                     

$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);                            

$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day                  


$numberDays = intval($numberDays);                                           

echo $numberDays;                                                            

echo floor((strtotime('04-04-2017')-strtotime('14-03-2017'))/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: I think you should +1 to whatever calculated days because output for any dates as per your requirement is not gonna give you output you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the number of days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the new DateTime extension, PHP 5.3+:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2010-07-06");
$date2 = new DateTime("2010-07-09");

// this calculates the diff between two dates, which is the number of nights
$numberOfNights= $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Comment: $date1 = new \DateTime("2010-07-06");
        $date2 = new \DateTime("2010-07-07"); || Returns 0...??

Comment: @octavian Doesn't work for `18-01-2019 16:00` (Friday) and `21-01-2019 08:00` (Monday). Returns 2, correct is 3 (nights).

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan https://3v4l.org/7ZfdD (it is working, it returns 1)

Comment: @JasomDotnet you are correct; the script described assumes the time part of the date is uncompleted hence it is 00:00 AM. If you loose the time part, it will work https://3v4l.org/iibiD

Comment: @Octavian time part is important sequence of information I don't want to cut :D

Answer (score -2):

check this out for calculating **nights**

```
$start_ts = strtotime("2019-10-05"); 
$end_ts = strtotime("2019-10-06"); 
$diff = $end_ts - $start_ts; 
echo round($diff / 86400);//1 night
```

work like charm