# Parsing String to Timestamp in order to find difference in days

Tags: php, string, laravel, date, parsing

I need to find the **difference in days** between two timestamps.

```
$now = date("Y-m-d");
//This return 2017-01-04

$last_active = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($user->updated_at->toDateTimeString())); 
//This returns for example: 2016-07-20

$datediff = $now - $last_active;
$days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

This code keeps returning 0 for $days.

However it seems that the `$now` and `$last_active` works as strings, and thereby i cant just substract the two from eachother, and then $days will simply return 0.

**How do I substract the two from eachother?** I need someway to parse them into some sort of variable, where I can substract the two.

---

**So far ive tried the following:**

[Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)
This does not work, because my variables are as strings, is my guess.

Also I have tried parsing the dates into integers, but this would result in, for example 20170104 - 20160720 which gives a value that has nothing to do with the difference in days from the two.

---

Hoping for some helpful pointers

Best Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Have you also tried it with the `diff()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` on the two dates for comparison, to calculate them both as the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch ( January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Example:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$last_active = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($user->updated_at->toDateTimeString())); 
$current = strtotime($now);
$last = strtotime($last_active);
$diff = $current - $last;
$days = floor($diff/(60*60*24));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Laravel, you can use Carbon out of the box. Use `diff...()` methods including `diffInDays`, `diffForHumans()` and others:

```
Carbon::parse($stringDate)->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
```

If you need compare two days (not difference from now), just use another `parse()` instead of `now()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily using Carbon.  http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

If you are working with strings, you should be able to use

```
$date1 = Carbon\Carbon::parse('January 4th 2017');
$date2 = Carbon\Carbon::parse('January 1st 2017');
```

That will give you two Carbon objects for which you can now use to compare.

```
$days = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
```

With Laravel timestamps, you get a carbon object out of the box.  So using your example you should be able to do this.

```
$days = $user->updated_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference in days using the PHP `diff()` function

```
$now = new DateTime();
$last_active = new DateTime($user->updated_at->toDateTimeString());
$interval = $now ->diff($last_active);
$difference = $interval->format('%a');
echo $difference;
```