# Calculate days in months between two dates with PHP

Tags: php

I have a period with startdate of `2016-12-26` and end date `2017-03-04`.

Now I would like to find out how many days in each months there is, from a given period. Expected output from the above period dates (array):

```
2016-12: 5
2017-01: 31
2017-02: 28
2017-03: 4
```

How can I accomplish this cleanest way? I have tried to:

1. first looking at the period_start, get the days = 26 and
2. find out the start/end dates of the months between 2016-12 and 2017-03, to then calculate the days here (31 respectively 28 in february)
3. then finally calculating the 4 days in 2017-03.

But is there any cleaner/better way?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: if you start from `2016-12-26` then `2016-12` would be `5` not `26`

Comment: yes exactly i i also wants to know how your desired days are calculated ?

Comment: just count the seconds between the dates then convert it to days

Comment: @Niklesh This is very true. My bad, 2016-12 should be 5

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved easily using the DateTime class. Create the objects, and use `DateTime::diff()` on them, then use the `days` property.

```
$start = new DateTime("2016-12-26");
$end = new DateTime("2017-03-04");

echo $start->diff($end)->days; // Output: 68
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Kbvs2)

- http://php.net/datetime.construct

Comment: Thanks, but I look for a solution that breaks down the days into months rather than the sum for the whole period.

Answer (score 1):

@Karem hope this logic will help you, this is working case for all your conditions please try this below one:

```
<?php
$startDate = '2016-12-26';
$endDate = '2017-03-04';
$varDate = $startDate;
while($varDate < $endDate){
    $d = date('d', strtotime($varDate));
    $Y = date('Y', strtotime($varDate));
    $m = date('m', strtotime($varDate));
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$m,$Y);
    $time = strtotime($varDate);
    if($varDate == $startDate){
        $time = strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $time));
        $days = $days - $d;
    }
    else if(date("Y-m", strtotime($varDate)) == date("Y-m", strtotime($endDate))){
        $days = date("j", strtotime($endDate));
    }
    echo date('Y-m', strtotime($varDate)). ": ".$days."<br>";
    $varDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", $time));
}
```

Comment: Thanks your for this! The per month is correct, but amount of days is wrong (26 should be 5, sorry for the mistake in question). So it should calculate how many days in there is in the month from 26th december (5). Also the static if($startDate == '2016-12-26' || $startDate == '2017-03-01') seems like a "quickfix" more than a proper solution that would work for any date periods

Comment: @Karem i have asked in the comment box, i thought it should be 26 ok let me update my answer

Comment: @Karem please check my updated answer, this is according to you

Comment: @ Niklesh i ll remember (y)

Answer (score 1):

This is long but easy to understand that how to achieve you your goal

```
<?php
  function getMonthDays($start,$end){
    if($start < $end){
      $start_time = strtotime($start);
      $last_day_of_start = strtotime(date("Y-m-t",$start_time));
      $start_month_days = ($last_day_of_start - $start_time)/(60*60*24);
      echo date("Y-m",$start_time).": ".$start_month_days."\n";
      $days = "";
      $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $start_time));
      $start_time = strtotime($start);
      while($start < $end){
        $month = date("m",$start_time);
        $year = date("Y",$start_time);
        $days = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
        echo date("Y-m",$start_time).": ".$days."\n";
        $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $start_time));
        $start_time = strtotime($start);
      }
      echo date("Y-m",strtotime($end)).": ".date("d",strtotime($end))."\n";

    }else{
      echo "Wrong Input";
    }
  }
  getMonthDays('2016-12-26','2017-03-04');
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/781724

Function returns array : https://eval.in/781741

Comment: I like this solution. Thank you for contribution. But why +1 month? 
Case: if period_start is the same as period_end, it should be 0 days. Case 2: getMonthDays('2016-12-26','2016-12-27'); fails

Comment: Great, thanks for this! Makes sense. Any way the day can be counted aswell? getMonthDays('2016-12-26','2016-12-27'); should return 2, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$d1 = strtotime('2016-12-26');
$d2 = strtotime('2017-03-04');
echo floor(($d2 - $d1)/(60*60*24));
?>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, how does this code produce a line for each month?

Answer (score 0):

i used Carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) but you can do it with any other time lib.

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', '2017-01-11');;
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', '2018-11-13');;

$diffInMonths = $endDate->diffInMonths($startDate);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $diffInMonths; $i++) {
    $start = $i == 0 ? $startDate->copy()->addMonth($i) : $startDate->copy()->addMonth($i)->firstOfMonth();
    $end = $diffInMonths == $i ? $endDate->copy() : $start->copy()->endOfMonth();

    echo $end->format('Y-m') . ' ' . ($end->diffInDays($start) + 1) . PHP_EOL;
}
```