# What is the limit when strotime() fails to return something?

Tags: php

I used this function to find remaining days in PHP

```
function days_until($date){
     return (isset($date)) ? floor((strtotime($date) - time())/60/60/24)+1 : FALSE;
}
```

> It's almost perfect except when it has to return any value greater than **7547**

An example case is when I tried to find `days_until('2038-01-20')`, today being **2017-05-22**, returns `-17308`. While the same for `days_until('2038-01-19')` returns `7547`. Can anyone tell me whats going on here? Its like `strtotime($date)` isn't even working, and returning 0.

Can anyone solve this, with an explanation, please?

Comment: Follow this question, [Date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) too.

Comment: `strtotime()` works with signed 32bit integers (on 32bit versions of PHP), so it overflows somewhere on 19 January 2038. See the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Answer (score 1):

As stated on a note from the [PHP Manual for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> **Note**:
>   The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)
>
> ...
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.