# How to calculate number of days in each month in php

Tags: php

need to calculate the number of days from current date to 27th of each month in PHP
In below code, it's calculating correctly for current month but if the current date is 28th it should calculate for next month.

```
$year = date("y");
$month = date("m");
$day = '27';

$current_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
$end_date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
$interval = $current_date->diff($end_date);
echo $interval->format('%a day(s)');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this script quick, because I don't have the time to test it yet.

**EDIT:**

```
$day = 27;
$today = date('d');

if($today < $day){
    $math = $day - $today;
    echo "There are " . $math . " days left until the 27th.";
} else {
    $diff = date('t') - $today;

    $math = $diff + $day;
    echo "There are " . $math . " days left until the 27th of the next month.";
}
```

Comment: for eg, today's date is 28th which means it goes to the else part and it should show the diff of this month 28th to next month 27 now it's showing the negative value .. :(

Answer (score 5):

Try php `cal_days_in_month` function

```
cal_days_in_month — Return the number of days in a month for a given year and calendar
```

Ex:

```
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003); // 31
echo "There were {$number} days in August 2003";
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Comment: buddy I need to calculate 27th to 27th of each month so month and year should be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
<?php
    $year = date("y");
    $month = date("m");
    $day = '27';

    $current_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
    $end_date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
    if($current_date->getTimestamp()<=$end_date->getTimestamp()){
        $interval = $current_date->diff($end_date);
        echo $interval->format('%a day(s)');
    }
    else{
        $interval = $end_date->diff($current_date);
        echo $interval->format('-%a day(s)');
    }
?>
```

Comment: for eg, today's date is 28th which means it goes to the else part and it should show the diff of this month 28th to next month 27.

Comment: Yes it goes to else part and display `-1 day(s)`. If you don't want remove else part or set `0` as a interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
$datediff = $now - $your_date;

echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Source : [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

by this....

```
<?php
  $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,10,2005);
  echo "There was $d days in October 2005";
?>
```