# How to find difference in months in YEAR-MONTH format in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have birth date of user in ('Y-m') format in database and I want to calculate his age in months and in Years in php.
How to do it ?

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Will that work for Y-m format as well ? I don't have date in birthdate column

Answer (score 3):

you can use php datetime object for it

- create a datetime object from the birthday
- create a datetime object from today date
- find the difference

  ```
  $today = new DateTime();
  $birthday = new DateTime('1994-11-27');
  $age = $today->diff($birthday);
  $ageString = $age->format('Y-m-d');
  echo $ageString;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

you can get difference by converting you date time to date time object and than here is code which take differnce

```
                $interval = $timeNow->diff($previousCheckOut[0]->getCheckOut());
                $differnce = $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
                $differnceDateTimeObj = new \DateTime($differnce);
```

let me know if you need any help

Comment: Can you explain more plz. how to do it ?

Comment: in above code timenow is dattime object and its is it buildin functions

Comment: & previousCheckOut[0]  and getCheckOut() ??

Comment: "$previousCheckOut[0]->getCheckOut()" give me dattime object time now is also a  datetime object