# Find the number of days between to date objects

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have two date objects like this:

`2018-01-17 22:50:30`
`2018-01-23 23:04:36`

And I am trying to find the number of days between them. What is the proper way to do this in Laravel/PHP? Is just subtracting them sufficient?

I tried the possible solution linked below and it has not been working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is tagged Laravel, you have access to [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which makes this easy:

Assuming both are [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instances:

```
$date1->diffInDays($date2);
```

Eloquent timestamps are automatically converted to Carbon instances for manipulation.

Comment: I agree that using Carbon is the best choice, especially because it is built into Laravel. If you are using a datetime field other than the timestamps, you must declare the field(s) in the protected $dates array on the model in order for them to be converted to Carbon objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 timestamps as string or unix epoch, you can just substract them and divide by 1 day in seconds: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
$datediff = $now - $your_date;

echo round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

If you are using DateTime objects: [Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

`$datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-01-17 22:50:30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-01-23 23:04:36');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');`