# Days spent between now and n date [PHP]

Tags: php

Okay! so we all have seen how to get days remaining between **NOW** and a **DATE in the future** Like I have in my simple code below:

**SAY: $endate =  a date in future (5 days from today);**

```
$start =  new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime($enddate);
$diff = $end->diff($start)->format('%a');
$days = intval($diff);
 
echo $days.'Days Remaining'; // 5 days Remaining
```

The above PHP Code is expected to show you how many days are left between **NOW** and the **FUTURE DATE**.

But what I want is the reverse of this situation. That is.

instead of having

```
5 Days Remaining
```

I need some thing like

```
0 Day(s) Spent //where today is day 0 of 5
```

Comment: You need to pass fix date in Start Date and Current Date in End Date

Comment: I am not totally sure what you are asking now I look again. Please give us some example dates for Start and End dates, and the answer you want based on those dates

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA, Your comment is appreciated. I think that's what I just need. the end date should be the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLUE TO ANSWER PROVIDED BY @KHIMAJI VALUKIYA in comment

The trick here is to set the start date not as current date but the actual date to start counting/calculating from.
Then the end date should be set to the current date.

```
$start =  new DateTime($enddate); //date to start counting from
$end = new DateTime(); //current date
$diff = $end->diff($start)->format('%a');
$days = intval($diff);
echo $days.'Days Spent'; // 5 Days Spent
```

Answer (score 0):

$start = new DateTime("2021-12-14");

$now = new DateTime();

$now_diff = $now->diff($start)->format("%a");

print_r($now_diff .' Day(s) Spent');

[Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: when you have it like this. it says (3 days)  today, tomorrow, it says 3 days... and the day after, it says 3 days. What I want is 0 day if it's today, then tomorrow, it will be 1 day, next tomorrow, will be 2 days up until the $later date is reached