# How to accurately sum the differences in years, months, and days across multiple date ranges in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have a list of periods defined as pairs of dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I would like to calculate the sum of years, months, and days for all the periods combined, taking into account the correct number of days in a month and leap years. Here is a sample list:

```php
$periods = [
    ['2023-06-26', '2023-09-01'], //0 Y, 2 M, 6 D   
    ['2023-01-01', '2023-06-21'], //0 Y, 5 M, 21 D    
    ['2021-05-01', '2022-06-25'], //1 Y, 1 M, 25 D
];
```

How can I achieve this in PHP? Are there any built-in functions or libraries I can use, or do I need to write a custom algorithm to calculate the date differences?

I this code but the results are not exact, only approximate:

```
$totalDays = 0;
$totalMonths = 0;
$totalYears = 0;

foreach ($periods as $period) {
    $start = date_create($period[0]);
    $end = date_create($period[1]);
    $diff = date_diff($start, $end);

    $totalDays += $diff->d + 1; 
    $totalMonths += $diff->m;
    $totalYears += $diff->y;
}

// Normalizacja dni i miesięcy
while ($totalDays >= 30) {
    $totalDays -= 30;
    $totalMonths += 1;
}

while ($totalMonths >= 12) {
    $totalMonths -= 12;
    $totalYears += 1;
}
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You could calculate the diffs each in seconds and sum them up. Afterwards you can simply calculate minutes, hours, days, ...

Comment: Since months are different lengths, what does it mean to convert a total in terms of months and days?

Comment: if you want to approximate all months to 30 days, calculate the total number of days. Divide by 360 to get years, divide the remainder by 30 to get months, and the final remainder is days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff might be worth considering

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to calculate the date interval inclusively, I added a one-day interval (i.e. "P1D") too.

```php
<?php

  function calculatePeriods (array $periods): DateInterval {
    $current = $initial = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $current = $initial;

    foreach ($periods as $period) {
      [$start, $end] = $period;
      $interval = (new DateTimeImmutable($end))->diff(new DateTimeImmutable($start));
      $current = $current->add($interval)->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    }

    return $current->diff($initial);
  }

  $periods = [
    ['2023-06-26', '2023-09-01'], //0 Y, 2 M, 6 D   
    ['2023-01-01', '2023-06-21'], //0 Y, 5 M, 21 D    
    ['2021-05-01', '2022-06-25'], //1 Y, 1 M, 25 D
  ];

  print_r(calculatePeriods($periods));
```

The result is something like:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1
    [m] => 9
    [d] => 16
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 654
    [from_string] =>
)
```

Comment: I found a work experience calculator and it shows  
 1 Y 9 M 23 D 

https://kalkulatory.gofin.pl/kalkulatory/kalkulator-stazu-pracy-1