# PHP: get number of days between two dates in format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)

Is there a quick and easy way to calculate the difference in days between two date strings in this format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) with PHP (not MySQL)?

Comment: duplicate of [How to find number of days between two dates using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php) and a couple others

Comment: @Gordon Bad choice; the accept answer there is wrong :p

Comment: @Artefacto Feel free to suggest another. But there is at least five other links to similar questions among the answers to the question I linked as duplicate. Linking to a question doesn't imply having to use the accepted answer does it?

Comment: @Gordon Upon checking the links, yours is actually the only that's an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Artefacto just believe me, this has been asked and answered before many times :) I am just too lazy to do the OP's work and find a better suited one. Like I said, feel free to find one more fitting.

Comment: *(useful)* [O'Reilly PHP Cookbook - Finding the Difference of Two Dates](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch03_06.htm)

Answer (score 16):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2010-07-06"); //inclusive
$date2 = new DateTime("2010-07-09"); //exclusive
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $diff->format("%a"); //3
```

(PHP 5.3 and higher only)

The only solution I see for PHP < 5.2 is to loop:

```
strtotime("-1 days");
strtotime("-2 days");
...
strtotime("-n days");
```

until we get to the unix timestamp of the first date. That's conceptually, you can do it in a much more efficient way, by first guessing the number of days with the timestamp difference of the two days and then testing the neighborhood.

#### Why dividing by 86400 doesn't work

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
$date1 = strtotime("2010-03-28");
$date2 = strtotime("2010-03-29");
echo ($date2-$date1)/86400; //gives 0.95833333333333
$date1 = strtotime("2010-10-31");
$date2 = strtotime("2010-11-01");
echo ($date2-$date1)/86400; //gives 1.0416666666667
```

As Gordon correctly has pointed out, dividing by 86400 would be a valid solution for this problem if the timezone was set to 'UTC' before – just don't forget to restore it to the previous value after.

Comment: +1 for using the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: +1 for using the DateTime class which is DST sensitive. (When using the correct time zone(s), of course.)

Comment: @Bog Granted, but PHP 5.1 and lower are not supported anymore; people shouldn't be using them – not that it stops them, of course.

Comment: RHEL/CentOS and all business distros use 5.1.6 (at the moment)

Comment: @Bog I mean they're not supported upstream, granted some distributions backport bug fixes.

Comment: @Bogdan Constantinescu,the limit version is 5.3 or higher.

Comment: @Spawn You're right, there was no DateTime::diff in 5.2. I added a note.

Comment: +1 for the <5.2 method with reference to testing the neighbourhood

Comment: @Artefacto as much as I agree to using DateTime, as much do I think it would be helpful for others to show them an Example when DST actually affects the outcome.

Comment: @Gordon I added two examples.

Comment: @Artefacto thanks, though it should be noted that this could easily be solved with setting `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` which doesnt know DST. The PEAR_Date package does it this way too I think.

Comment: @Gordon That's a good idea, and it actually solves this particular problem. It only starts to fall apart in cases where the timezone is significant (e.g. calculating future times, difference between two arbitrary times, etc.).

Comment: @Artefacto yepp, I am happy now. With that added, I can upvote. Enjoy your Nice Answer badge.

Comment: Thanks for this guys, how can i deal with minus numbers with this solution - or more specifically, how can i get __$in_the_past = TRUE;__ ?

Comment: @Har `$days = $diff->format("%a"); $in_the_past = ($days < 0);`

Comment: @Artefacto - your original example keeps returning 6015? I'm using php 3.50 on WAMP

Comment: @Har I don't know what you're doing wrong... It does return `3`. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/TTIrAR BTW, I think you meant PHP 5.3.

Comment: @Artefacto even if i copy your exact code into a new php file i still get '6015' - i notice that the tester you were using (looks like a really useful tool) uses 5.3dev could this be sometihing to do with it?

Comment: @Har I've no idea what's happening. Try updating to the latest version of PHP and if you're still getting differences of over 16 years submit a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to get the number of days between two `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`:

```
function dateDiff($dateStart, $dateEnd) 
{
    $start = strtotime($dateStart);
    $end = strtotime($dateEnd);
    $days = $end - $start;
    $days = ceil($days/86400);
    return $days;
}
```

Comment: thanks this looks great, will accept your answer when it lets me!

Comment: This has the same problem as @Mark's answer; it doesn't consider daylight saving time.

Comment: DateTime class is only php 5.2 or higher. I can show you all major stable business distros use php 5.1 (take for example RHEL/CentOS)

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the Duplicate I've linked below the question.

---

The following SO questions might be of some help:

- [How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)
- [Dates difference with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803003/dates-difference-with-php)
- [Calculate the difference between date/times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074290/calculate-the-difference-between-date-times-in-php)
- [Date Difference in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php)
- [Getting the difference between two time/dates using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770564/getting-the-difference-between-two-time-dates-using-php)

[More >>](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+date+difference)