# PHP difference between dates

Tags: php

I am developing game and I need to show to player, how much day he is under protection. This is what I have for now:

```
if(user::loged()){
  $protect = (60*60*24*8) - (time() - user::info['reg_date']);
  $left = date("n",$protect);
  if($left > 0) echo "You are protected for $left days!";
}
```

For first (test) user `reg_date` is 1394883070 (15.3.2014 11:31). So it should print

`You are protected for 7 days!`

But I get that

`You are protected for 1 days!`

Any ideas?

Comment: It has 1394883070, from database (I wrote it)

Comment: You're better off using Date Diff. I'm on my phone so I can't give much info. But here's the doc URL: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: get number of days between two dates in format YYYY-MM-DD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185168/php-get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set $left to the number of months.

n is Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros - http://php.net/date

I would do

```
if(user::loged()){
  $protect = 691200 - (time() - user::info['reg_date']);
  $left = ceil($protect / 86400);
  if($left > 0) echo "You are protected for $left days!";
}
```

Comment: Still as Lajos Veres suggests, date is the wrong thing to use here.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
$days_since_registration = (time() - user::info['reg_date'])/(24*3600)
```

date() is useful for only unix timestamps. The difference of timestamps is a time interval in seconds, if you use it as a timestamp you are using dates in 1970 or something similar happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $protect = (60*60*24*8) - (time() - user::info['reg_date']);
   $left = ltrim(date("d",$protect), 0);
   if($left > 0) echo "You are protected for $left days!";
   // Prints "You are protected for 7 days!"
?>
```