# Why PHP is returning wrong days between two dates?

Tags: php, date

There are a ton of such questions on Stackoverflow and before you mark this as duplicate, let me tell you that none of those work in my case.

[Date Difference in php on days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days)

[Calculate the difference between date/times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074290/calculate-the-difference-between-date-times-in-php)

[Dates difference with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803003/dates-difference-with-php)

[Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Above are the questions I have checked. The last question has an answer by `Jurka` which also unfortunately doesn't works. So here is my code:

```
$date1 = new DateTime(date('d-m-y'));
$date2 = new DateTime($etaDate);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";
```

The `$etaDate` in above case is 03-02-16 and the current date is 08-02-16 so it should return 5 days but it returns a very high figure - 1826 days. I have tried different methods which also returns the same day figure.

A date value is stored as string in database so on retrieving I am again putting it back to date format using this code:

```
$newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $EntryDate);
$newdate->add(new DateInterval('P15D'));
$etaDate = $newdate->format('d-m-y');
```

`$EntryDate` is a variable that holds the date from the database, `$etaDate` converts it into date format.

Comment: So what format is `03-02-16` and `08-02-16` - Is that 16th February 2003 and 16th February 2008? If you feed ambiguous values into PHP's date functions, then you may not get the expected outputs

Comment: @MarkBaker No, its 3rd Feb 2016 and 8th Feb 2016.

Comment: `$etaDate` considered `2003-02-16`. How are you getting that date?

Comment: @Sougata I did echo $etaDate and it shows 03-02-16

Comment: How is PHP expected to know the date format if a human being can't say for certain what date it is

Comment: You need to change the date format.

Comment: @MarkBaker My both dates are in this format only - 'd-m-y'

Comment: Then you need to tell PHP that is the format that you're using: `$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $etaDate);`
`

Comment: @MarkBaker That's what I did, you can see that in the last part of the question.

Comment: I have answered solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060175/219112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the format of year from `y to Y` and it will work.

See the example : https://eval.in/514811

Comment: Using 'd-m-y', I am inserting into database so I have to use 'y' only. 16 cannot be compared to 2016.

Comment: You can always change your date format when you want to insert into database.

Comment: Yeah that is true but what is the problem with 'd-m-y' format because it is also valid.

Comment: Problem is in `03-02-16`. How can PHP identify `year` in this format?

Comment: In the last part of question, I have mentioned how I arrived at that date, using this: `$etaDate = $newdate->format('d-m-y');` So PHP knows I am using this format.

Comment: It is really risky task to use two digit format for year. i suggest you to use four digit. How will you know that `16` is `2016` or `1916`?

Comment: Yeah never thought about that, changed `y` to `Y` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code
//YYYY-MM-DD format

```
$etaDate="2016-02-03";
$date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$date2 = new DateTime($etaDate);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";
```